# 12 leds diveded by 4leds input 12 volts from motorcycle what resistor i use to it every four leds

Tags: led

[image]

I use this as my headlight to my motorcycle. I know if i connect derictly to motorcyle will damage in a few days.[image][image][image]

Comment: Can you get a model number for this part?

Comment: There is no model

Comment: You need to be clear on what you need and in your question too. Without schematic or circuit diagram, model number it is difficult to resolve

Comment: Friend can you check  my diagram if right.

Comment: It seems source voltage is not enough. You mention clearly, a forward voltage of a single LED is 3.6V, hence for a four LED in a row, would be 14.4V not 12V. Double check it

Comment: What if the voltage of led is 3.0 volts or 2.5 volts its lead how much the resistor?

Comment: Why did you provide 3.6V as the forward voltage of the LED? Where did that number come from?

Comment: May i ask again,what if you dont know what the exactly voltage of Led, so how do i know or any proccedure to determine its?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the info, you have given in schematic, there is a possibility of source voltage must be higher than you have mentioned. In general, standard LED's have a forward voltage around 2V or more.So, in your case, it is 3.6V. Since you have connected 4 LED in series, the total forward voltage of those LEDs will be

4*3.6 = 14.4V.

In addition, the forward current value is 20mA for an LED. In a series connection, current will not be changed but in a parallel circuit, the current will branched.In your circuit, three branches are there. Hence, in order to provide 20mA for each branch. the total load current from the source needed is 60mA.

If you have taken standard 24V DC input source, then a resistor needed to limit the current will be,

```
 R = (Vin - Vf) / I
 R = (24 - 14.4) / 60 mA
 R = 160 ohm
```

Here is the simulation of the circuit with the mentioned values above.

[image]

**Note:** 
         Arrows filled with blue color denotes that LED is glowing.

Comment: Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Dhans, i already tried those LED to motorcycle with 4 Leds in every row 12/4=3. But the brightness are enough. No resistor at all,it is alright? The input of motorcycle is 12volts. Becuase i have no idea what exactly  its Voltage  of LED. Do you have any idea to know the Voltage of its LED?

Comment: Yes. Regarding LEDs without resistors are not recommended since it is not safe to LEDs while more current passes from source due to increased voltage and LED will fail. 

To measure a voltage  between LED pins, power up LEDs and measure voltage between cathode and anode of a single LED in any row using multimeter

Comment: Also, if the input of the LED circuit is 12V, then the voltage across LED must not be 3.6V as you said but around 2V. Check it clearly